# Spider returns only "[" in the items.json file

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote the spider to extract an image out of a website. But the items.json file only has [ character in it. 
Please help me.
My spider file is this:-

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from captcha.items import CaptchaItem

class CaptchaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "CaptchaSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["*****.ac.in"]
    start_urls = [
      "https://*****.ac.in/*****.asp"
    ]

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = CaptchaItem()
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item['im'] = hxs.select('//img/@src').extract()
    return item
```

My items.py file is this:-

```
import scrapy


class CaptchaItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    im = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample webpage and the expected output?

Comment: Nothing in this code refers to a file named `items.json`. It's like asking a veterinarian to diagnose your dog, but only showing him his leash and his food bowl. :) It seems like whatever is exporting the JSON file breaks during the serialisation.

Comment: @Amadan I use the command scrapy crawl CaptchaSpider -o items.json
to generate the json .

Comment: @CommuSoft I want to scrap captcha image out of this URL : https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output file would contain only `[` if there was an error while crawling or, there were no items returned.

In your case, it is because of the indentation, `parse_item()` should be indented:

```
class CaptchaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "CaptchaSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["*****.ac.in"]
    start_urls = [
      "https://*****.ac.in/*****.asp"
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = CaptchaItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item['im'] = hxs.select('//img/@src').extract()
        return item
```

I've actually tested and reproduced it:

```
$ scrapy runspider spider.py -o items.json
...
$ cat items.json
[
```

Comment: I am a newbie. Could u please elaborate ?

Comment: @Aayush see the `parse_item()` method is on the same indentation level as `class` - this is not correct. I've provided a fixed version in the answer, should work for you.

Comment: thanks but it still didn't get me the image I am trying to download. It's actually a captcha image. I am still getting [ in my json file.

Comment: @Aayush difficult to tell without having an actual link to work with.

Comment: thanks for your support. I used beautifulsoup instead and solved my problem.